# Mysql DB returns wrong date format (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, date, select, culture

This is a very simple question about a confusing circumstance with my C#-App:

**Usings:**
C# Desktop-App / Mysql 5.5

**Whats going on:**
My app is selection some data from the db (`Select date from mytable`). The format for column `date` is `yyyy-mm-dd`. After retrieving the data inside my C#-App im getting a culture-sensitive output. In my case in format `dd.mm.yyyy`. Check out my screenshot from debugging.

Notice: **The var `listDate` is from type `string`!**
[image]

My output looks like from type DateTime. But I've never converted it into dateTime. The column(db) `date` is set to format `date`.

So why am I getting this format? Is it a db or app problem?
My goal is to get the same format `yyyy-mm-dd` as inside the db.

Every help appreciated. Thanks very much!!!

**EDIT 1:**

My code:

```
public static void DB_Select(string s, params List<string>[] lists)
        {
            try
            {
                using(var conn = new MySqlConnection(ServerConnection))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    string command = s;
                    cmd.CommandText = command;
                    using(var sqlreader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    while (sqlreader.Read())
                    {
                        if (sqlreader[0].ToString().Length > 0)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < lists.Count(); i++)
                            {
                                lists[i].Add(sqlreader[i].ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (List<string> save in lists)
                            {
                                save.Add("/");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error while selecting data from database!\nDetails: " + ex);
            }
        }
```

Cant imagine this could be the problem. All this is doing is looping through the output and saving the single columns into different passed lists (`params List<string>[]`)

**Using:**

```
Services.DB_Select("SELECT date FROM myTable WHERE something = something")
```

So everything is kept into strings without any converts. It is only about the select and the output db -> c#. Im selecting a date-format and getting a dateTime value culture-sensitive. How is this possible?

**EDIT 2: (SOLUTION)**

If I get it like `SELECT CONCAT(date) FROM mytable...` (telling the db to handle (col)date as a string I get the clean output yyyy-mm-dd !

Without concat I get my dateTime output culture-sensitive. So it has to be a problem with my date-format for the `date` column. But why - really dont know.

Comment: Can you please show your work as a text as well? I think it can be just a debugger representation. By the way, are you sure MySQL `date` keep's it's value in a specific format? In SQL Server, it keeps `datetime` and `datetime2` as a binary for example.

Comment: How are you getting the SELECT statement into the `listDate` variable? Not much we can do to help unless we see the code.

Comment: Please include the (short) code which demonstrates the problem.(I would expect date columns to be returned back as `DateTime` values: if you are getting text you may be doing it wrong.)

Comment: No problem. Not that I was too lazy. I just thought the problem would be visible this way. Ill edit it in some minutes.

Comment: So this line here is converting everything to a string `sqlreader[i].ToString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alright, a college of mine told me a solution. At least it sounds logic to me:**

The col itself is from type `date` which is a short version of `dateTime`. When using a clear select like `SELECT date FROM mytable` the output will come as a `DateTime`. Thats why I also get the time-part inside my output.

When going for `SELECT CONCAT(date) FROM mytable` the value is handled like a string. A workaround I found myself. This will only output the date itself.

Strange behaviour. For sure because I work with this date-formatted-column for a long time. Never had any problems with it.

Thanks a lot for your interest!

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide how you get the data from DB it's hard to say. There are probably two options - 1) some kind of implicit conversion done when retrieving data, so you get the formatted string from db or 2) you do the conversion somewhere after you get the data.

What you could do is conversion to DateTime
`listDate.Select(d => DateTime.ParseExact(d,"dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))` and then format it back to format that you need.

Better solution would of course be getting the date in DateTime directly from DB. Please post your code for this.

EDIT

The problem there is that sqlreader[i].ToString() - this takes your Culture from Environment and does the conversion. In that case I would check for type of the value and if that is DateTime then use ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") instead of simple ToString()

From documentation:

> This method uses formatting information derived from the current
>   culture. In particular, it combines the custom format strings returned
>   by the ShortDatePattern and LongTimePattern properties of the
>   DateTimeFormatInfo object returned by the
>   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat property. For more
>   information, see CultureInfo.CurrentCulture. Other overloads of the
>   ToString method enable you to specify the culture whose formatting to
>   use and to define the output pattern of the DateTime value.

Comment: I provided the code. Just 3 minutes before your post. :)

Comment: Just for info you just moved your conversion logic to the select statement. You will have to think of it every time you use it for selecting datetimes. ;)

Comment: It wasnt a culture-problem. My problem is that the output of the date-value in my database also brought a time-part with it. So it went from date to dateTime without any logical reason for me. I never cared about the format of the dateTime output itself.

Comment: I think you still do not understand this. As you pointed out when you do SELECT date FROM mytable you get DateTime as output. Then in C# the object you get is not string but also DateTime - you got this and you did the conversion in C# with that .ToSting() call = culture specific. But in you solution you do this conversion on database server, so in C# you do not get DateTime object, but plain string.

Comment: I for sure know that im converting with .ToString(). Bit the culture isnt important in any way is it? My problem was about getting the DateTime and not the date as a string. The culture itself is only a thing about the format of the dateTime right? This way everything is clear for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The culture is important for the ToString() call. The output string depends on it. DateTime is just DateTime, it's the same no matter what culture. Culture specifies the format of the string that will be on output of the ToString() call on DateTime object.

Comment: Dude.... on `dateTime`. I dont want to have `DATETIME` ^^. THATS the problem. I only needed the date, not the datetime. So this whole culture-thing is irelevant. Selecting the field with concat returns the plain string from the database. Thats my solution.